# What is the difference between "guide" and "guideline"

Tags: meaning

For example,

the following is a guide for ...

the following is a guideline for ...

My understanding is that a guide is like "help" for something. While, a guideline is like a "rule" for something.

Comment: Have you tried the very good online dictionaries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Guideline* has a more specific meaning and often  a more formal usage, while *guide* is a more generic term.

**[Guideline](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Guideline)**:
A statement or other indication of policy or procedure by which to determine a course of action.

- official guidelines for the prevention of flu.
- guidelines to the implementation of economic directives.

**[Guide](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/guide?q=guide)**: Something that serves to direct or indicate.

- a shopper's guide
- guide to the use of electronic devices.